# Problem with xcolor package

Tags: color

With the folowing file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{N}{p{1.5cm}}

\begin{tabular}[c]{cN}
  One & Two 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I get this error

```
Use of \@startpbox doesn't match its definition
```

In the output file I obtain

```
23 One
```

If I use the array package instead of the xcolor package, the file will compile properly.

So, what's happening?

(I'm using TeX Live 2018 just updated.)

Comment: there is a  small error in colortbl (loaded by the table option). With tomorrows update it should be okay again.

Comment: sorry you need the latest version of colortbl (which is on ctan now but should get to texlive in the next day or so)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by an update of the buggy package ...